# xquery in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

what is the best xquery method to get the max attribute value from the document. Eg

```
    <organizations>
       <organization id="1"/>
       <organization id="6"/>
       <organization id="11"/>
    </organizations>
```

I want the query to return 11.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml = '
<organizations>
  <organization id="1"/>
  <organization id="6"/>
  <organization id="11"/>
</organizations>'

select @xml.value('max(/organizations/organization/@id)', 'int')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<organizations>
       <organization id="1"/>
       <organization id="6"/>
       <organization id="11"/>
    </organizations>'


SELECT
    MAX(org.value('(@id)[1]', 'int'))
FROM
    @input.nodes('/organizations/organization') AS Orgs(Org)
```

You need to use `.nodes()` to get a list of all possible values, and then apply `MAX()` to that list of integer values.

Answer (score 0):

The XQuery snippet you're looking for is `max(/organizations/organization/@id)`.